# Is it possible to refresh markerclustering with checkbox?

Tags: checkbox, maps, marker, markerclusterer

I have got map http://www.goget.pl/mapa.html and a lot of markers in different categories. After clicking on checkbox only markers disappear but clustering is still the same.

Did anybody meet with the same problem?

Comment: I am hitting this same issue, did you find a way to refresh a cluster map? I am changing the geoJSON markers remotely on a 'vote' and was wondering how I could update the map accordingly. Any idea?